# Passing information from an open form to an open form on TextChanged event

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I am still learning C# so forgive me if this is a silly question and also forgive the long post as I am not certain on how to say this other then the "long" way.

My scenario:

I am using [DockPanel Suite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite/) for my application and I have a `ParentForm` a `NotesForm` and `BrowserForm` (I actually have quite a few more of the `BrowserForm` types but if I can get it working to one I should be able to make it work to the others)

So `ParentForm` loads at application start and when it loads it loads up the `NotesForm` and the `BrowserForm` is loaded via a button click event from the `ParentForm` and then that instance is open and stays open and will not close.

So by the time I enter information into the `NotesForm` I already have an established instance all 3 forms. (I think thats the problem)

My goal is to get information that is typed in `textBox1` on the `NotesForm` to a string variable lets call it `notesText` on the `BrowserForm` without having to click anything on the `NotesForm` which I would assume would be via the `TextChanged` event.

I am currently able to get the information over to the form using properties (get, set) but i have to click a button on the `NotesForm` and on the `BrowserForm` to make it happen.

I am including a kind of dumbed down code to show how I currently do it now. My full code is quite large so just trying to save confusion and show the concept of what I have going.

> Parent Form

```
public partial class parentForm : Form
{
    private notesForm notesForm = new notesForm();
    public parentForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    private void parentForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        notesForm.Show(mainDock, DockState.DockLeft);

    }
    private void tb1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BrowserForm.notesText= notesForm.passInfo;
    }
```

> NotesForm

```
public partial class notesForm : DockContent
{
    private string _passInfo;
    public notesForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    public string passInfo
    {
        get { return textBox1.Text; }
        set
        {
            _passInfo = value;
            textBox1.Text = _passInfo;
        }
    }

}
```

> BrowserForm

```
public partial class BrowserForm : DockContent
{
    private string passInfo;
    public BrowserForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
            public string passInfo
    {
        get
        {
            return _passInfo;
        }
        set
        {
            _passInfo = value;
            notesText = _passInfo;
        }

    }
    string notesText;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    MessageBox.Show(notesText);
    }
    }

}
```

So this currently works but to make it work I have to click a button on the parent form and then on the browserform. Ideally I need it to pass that information to the browser form after you have finished typing it in the textbox on the notes form. If it helps the information being typed into the textbox is static and will always be 9 chars long and consist of numbers (a phone number).

Also some background of what my application does. I use it for my job to access the various tools in our intranet. It auto logs you in consolidates them into one application versus having 40 - 80 different browser windows open and will eventually (hopefully) scrape some information from those tools automatically so we do not have to search the pages for it. The tool will just automatically pull it. This is nothing malicious and I'm not a spammer or anything I do ISP technical support for 10 different companies each of which have 8-10 tools for their services.

Any assistance with this would be appreciated or if there would be an easier way to go about what I am doing I would be happy to hear as well. Also if you would like to see my entire code (if it helps) let me know and I don't mind posting it is just very cumbersome.

Comment: holy wall of text Ben Affleck

Comment: @Jonesy lol I know sorry probably over kill but better then those annoying short questions that have no meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if got your question right. I assume you want to pass information from one child-form to another.

One way of doing that would be like this:

**1. Create an interface like this:**

```
public interface IDataContainer
{
     void SetData(String data);
}
```

**2. Let your `parentForm` implement your interface:**

```
public partial class parentForm : Form, IDataContainer
```

And give the method an implementation in the form class. This simple interface will enable implementors to store (string) data for whatever purpose.

In your case the implementation of the `SetData` method will act as a bridge, conecting the `notesForm` to your `BrowserForm`, passing data between the forms, in a *clean way*:

```
public partial class parentForm : Form, IDataContainer
[...]

public void SetData(String dataComingFromOtherSource)
{
     this.browserFormInstance.passInfo = dataComingFromOtherSource;
}
[...]
```

**3. Add a parameter typed `IDataContainer` to the constructor of each *child-form*** so that you can pass a reference to in `IDataContainer` implementation (that will be your `parentForm`). In this way:

```
public partial class parentForm : Form
{
    private notesForm notesForm = null;

    public parentForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Note that at this point you are instantiating
        // the child-form and you are passing a reference
        // to the `parentForm` so that you can pass information
        // to it, and from it to whatever other form you may
        // need, in an elegant way.
        this.notesForm = new notesForm(this);
    }
```

**4. Finally, at `notesForm`, put the logic to set the data in your `container`:**

```
public partial class notesForm : DockContent
{
    // On runtime this will in fact the `parentForm` object instance.
    IDataContainer myDataContainerInstance = null;

    public notesForm(IDataContainer myDataContainerInstance) : base()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Assign the reference so that you can use it later
        this.myDataContainerInstance = myDataContainerInstance;

        textBox1.TextChanged += new EventHandler(textBox1_TextChanged);
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.myDataContainerInstance.SetData(textBox1.Text);
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** Having an static class/**singleton** will be also a solution, and much simpler by the way...

Comment: This is great. This is exactly the type of thing i have been looking for as a whole for my program. Using properties is a bit dirty when you have so many different forms you need to pass to and all the different instances have been giving me a headache. I tried doing something like this in the past but i couldnt get it working properly. Thanks a lot i will try and implement this tonight!

Comment: Glad to hear it ;) Let us know if it the implementation went fine.

Comment: Aha it worked!! Awesome thanks!! Now to essentially rewrite everything in this manner lol. Will be tedious but much cleaner and easier to understand whats going on in the code

Comment: So working great but as a curiosity what if i wanted to add another textbox to this later down the road?

Comment: In that case, and to support with the same mechanism different behaviors in the *controller* (your `parentForm`), you may change the signature of the method `SetData` to accept a custom class, let's say `MyInterchangeData`. In that class you may add two properties, one will be the data itself (`Object data`), and the other one could be a new `Enum` type (that you need to declare), let's say we name it `KindOfDataEnum`, and the field `KindOfDataEnum kindOfData`. `parentForm` will decide then what to do upon receiving different values of `KindOfDataEnum`. The base mechanism will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to hook up the `TextChanged` event in the NotesForm, like this:

```
public partial class notesForm : DockContent
{
    public notesForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox1.TextChanged += new EventHandler(textBox1_TextChanged);
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Get value of text box here and either pass it to the Browser form 
        // via its constructor or get an instance of the Browser form and use 
        // the set of a property in the Browser form to store the value 
        string theTextBoxValue = textBox1.Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Karl
I do believe this is what i was looking for (Not much experience with events) Thanks!
How would i pass it via the constructor?